# TSQL XML Parsing on select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am using a select statement to query some results from my database. One of those columns contains XML data that I need to access.

```
SELECT A.[id],
A.[empID],
A.[licensePlate],
A.[carColor],
A.[carModel],
 (
 SELECT  ParamValues.x2.value('empID[0]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
 FROM   A.[carPoolMembers].nodes('/carPool/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)  
 )
FROM   licensePlates as A
WHERE  empID = @empID
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('results');
```

Here is what the XML looks like in that row:

    `<carPool>
       <employee>
        <empID>123</empID>
       </employee>
      <employee>
       <empID>456</empID>
      </employee>
    </carPool>`

I am getting this error when running the stored procedure:
    `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Any ideas on how to pull the XML from the row and parse it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you could just run the sub-select:

```
 SELECT  ParamValues.x2.value('empID[0]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
 FROM   A.[carPoolMembers].nodes('/carPool/employee')
```

It would return more than 1 row, which necessarily breaks the query.

Normally a sub-select can be correlated to the outer select, you just need to determine how to identify the specific value of the multiples returned that you want included in your outer-select.

Comment: I tried this and I now get this error : `Invalid object name 'A.carPoolMembers.nodes'.`

Comment: That's my whoops, I saw a typical sub-query problem and failed to notice that `A.[carPoolMembers].nodes('/carPool/employee')` is a value of `licensePlates`.  Why do you have the sub-select at all?

Comment: I need to get the empID's and then JOIN another table with the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you want the resulting structure to be.

Assuming you want multiple rows with this data, one for each employee ID in the carPoolMembers XML block, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT A.[id],
A.[empID],
A.[licensePlate],
A.[carColor],
A.[carModel],
ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS carPoolEmpID
FROM   licensePlates as A
CROSS APPLY A.[carPoolMembers].nodes('/carPool/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)
WHERE  empID = @empID
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('results');
```

This will only show rows that have at least one employee in the car pool.  If you want to show all employees regardless of car pool settings, you can use OUTER APPLY instead.

Comment: Here is a link to what the final outcome will look like. However, once I am able to get that part working, I need to be able to JOIN another table on the value of empID within the carpool tags. http://oi58.tinypic.com/9fo94z.jpg

Comment: I tried this and it worked however its treating records that have multiple carpool people as new records. So one vehicle is now 2 separate records because there were 2 carpool empID's

Comment: If you want to join another table based on the carpool empID values, I don't see another way to do this than to create new rows for each empID value.  You can then do the JOIN you need and then de-duplicate as needed after that point.